# Hibernate session closed with large volume

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to retrieve the data from a table linked to a parent table with the following entities:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "REF_BONJOUR_UNITE")
@NamedQuery(name = "UniteEntity.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UniteEntity u")
public class UniteEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "CODE_UNITE")
private String codeUnite;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to Insee
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "refBonjourUnite", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  CascadeType.MERGE )
    private List<Insee> refBonjourInsees;
```

and the daughter entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_BONJOUR_INSEE")
@NamedQuery(name = "Insee.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Insee i")
public class Insee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private InseePK id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "DATE_FIN_INSEE_GEO")
@IsOracleDate
private Date dateFinInseeGeo;

private String tylemt;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to UniteEntity
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CODE_UNITE_FK", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private UniteEntity refBonjourUnite;
```

When i try to access this list with a large amount of data, i get a failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, here exactly :

```
List<Insee> codeInsees = unite.getRefBonjourInsees();
Insee codeInsee = codeInsees.get(0)
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? If yes can you please provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Yes I have one : org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Comment: so are you saying this works with just a few data? What's the behavior if you change this: `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to this: `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`?

Comment: and from where do you access the collection? is the transaction active?

Comment: I have a thread of 4 so when I change the FetchType.LAZY to EAGER for one, the error is reported on the second